# Connecting Flutter to a Self-hosted Supabase in Docker

Tags: flutter, docker, supabase, supabase-flutter

As a beginner in Flutter and Supabase, I am trying to run the code found in the Supabase document [here](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/getting-started/quickstarts/flutter).  I think my Supabase account is set-up correctly since I can accessed the Supabase dashboard `http://localhost:8000` with the modifications in the `.env` and I have created and inserted the sample data. Here is the code, with a modification in the table since I used a schema *supatest* for the table:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Supabase.initialize(
    url: 'http://localhost:8000',
    anonKey:
        'KEY_REDACTED_BUT_IT_IS_THE_SAME_IN_DOTENV',
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Countries',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final _future = Supabase.instance.client.from('supatest.countries').select();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        future: _future,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          final countries = snapshot.data!;
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: countries.length,
            itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
              final country = countries[index];
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(country['name']),
              );
            }),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However, when I tried to run it, the CircularProgressIndicator just keeps spinning.  When using the dev tool of the browser, the error was: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`.  Drilling down to the URL which caused the error `http://localhost:8000/rest/v1/supatest.countries?select=%2A`, the page was displaying '**Kong Error** No API key found in request.'  What was wrong with the code or did I miss some configuration?  The anonKey is correct, it is the same with the one found in the .env.

Additional information:
pubspec.yaml

```
...
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  supabase_flutter: ^2.3.2
```

Comment: The URL to connect to your Supabase instance and the URL for the dashboard should be different, but are you confident they are both `http://localhost:8000`? Also, do you really have a table named `supatest.countries` with a period in its name? You generally want to use snake case for naming your Postgres stuff to avoid unwanted errors.

Comment: I installed Supabase locally using [Docker](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/self-hosting/docker) . I followed all the instructions except that I change the keys as recommended for security.  The table was created with a schema 'supatest' to distinguish it with the other tables in the future since I noticed that there is no create New Database / Project option in the Dashboard for Supabase that was hosted locally.

Comment: Understood about the URL. About the schema, you cannot access the `countries` table in your `supabase` schema with `supabase.from('supabase.countries')`. Also there is a whole other setup you have to do to query non-public schema from your API, so to test things out, just create a table in the public schema, and access it with `supabase.from('countries')` to see if it works.

Comment: I did what you suggested, created the table as is in the document, meaning in public schema and it worked!  So what can I do if there is a non-public schema if I want my previous scenario.

Comment: You can read about using custom schemas here. https://supabase.com/docs/guides/api/using-custom-schemas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found in dshukertjr's comment.  I had declared a schema and been using it to create and query the tables. Apparently, this needs additional configuration. Instead, I created the tables using the (default) public schema and it worked!